# UICollectionView inside ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I would like to implement a **UICollectionView inside my ViewController** and I'm a little bit lost because I'm trying to read tutorials and find some good guides, but I'm unable to implement it.

I have a UICollectionView created in an another App, and it's using a **UICollectionViewController**, now I need to put that code inside a **ViewController** (without the UICollectionViewController), and it's hard for me because it's my first time implementing that view inside a ViewController.

*Can you help me with some tutorial, guide or example? I want to know how to do this.*

**I have followed this tutorial to create the UICollectionView:** http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial#Adding_a_Collection_View_Controller_to_the_Storyboard and now I need to put that CollectionView in my "App" where it is going to show the user images, so in my top I'm going to have the username, userpicture, etc, etc and in the bottom I'm going to have the UICollectionView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your storyboard, add a "Container View" to "ViewController". This adds a view to the view to the view controller and a "View Controller Scene" to your storyboard with a view controller at the end of "Storyboard Embed Segue". This view controller will control the content shown in the embedded view. Assign the "Custom Class" of the view controller at the end of the embed segue to be your collection view controller.

I am not at my iMac right now, so cannot supply screenshots. Give me a shout if you need them to understand what I trying to describe.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you show me those screenshots? Can you also provide a good tutorial to follow? I understand that your answer is to create like a 'frame', right? Thanks @Lev Landau.